# C++ multiple operator=()

Tags: c++, operators, implicit-conversion, conversion-operator, explicit-conversion

I'm writing a String class. I'd like to be able to assign my strings such as;

```
a = "foo";
printf(a);
a = "123";
printf(a);
int n = a; // notice str -> int conversion
a = 456; // notice int -> str conversion
printf(a);
```

I've already assigned my operator=() method for string to integer conversion. How can I declare another operator=() so that I can do the reverse method?

When I declare another, it seems to override the previous.

```
String::operator const char *() {
    return cpStringBuffer;
}
String::operator const int() {
    return atoi(cpStringBuffer);
}
void String::operator=(const char* s) {
    ResizeBuffer(strlen(s));
    strcpy(cpStringBuffer, s);
}
bool String::operator==(const char* s) {
    return (strcmp(cpStringBuffer, s) != 0);
}

//void String::operator=(int n) {
//  char _cBuffer[33];
//  char* s = itoa(n, _cBuffer, 10);
//  ResizeBuffer(strlen(_cBuffer));
//  strcpy(cpStringBuffer, _cBuffer);
//}
```

Comment: Note: this "str -> int conversion" and the opposite, probably does not do what you think it does.

Comment: This isn't homework. I was inspired to make a String class that mimics functional language strings because I got sick of doing the conversions myself.

Comment: I don't see what automatic conversion have to do with a functional language (Haskell will scream at you, when you try something like this.) And why do conversions yourself? There are conversion functions.

Comment: @kvanberendonck does it mimic **functional** languages??? Actually it mimic languages with dynamic type system (and if it's what you need then you should consider to use ANOTHER language instead of C++ because often type-safety is his reason to be).

Comment: I do not know c++ so maybe I should not answer, but it seems to me that  `a = 456` would be possible but not `int n = a`. If you declare an equal operator, then `foo = bar` would (i think) always use the = operator of the object on the left hand side (i.e. foo). So, to have `int n = a`, you would need to have an int class which defines an = operator with a string as a parameter.

Comment: I put up the code I'm using. The one that's commented out is the one I'd like to work. Reading the current replies and messing around with them as we speak.

Comment: @Alderath: It can be done, and has in the question, by providing implicit conversions The `operator int()` defined above will be called when a `String` is used in a context where an `int` is required (handwaving here), but also in many contexts where it could be unwanted (where an `int` *could* be used)

Comment: @kvanberendonck: What is the problem with the code you have commented out? (the problems with the design are multiple, but what is wrong with that particular implementation?)

Comment: The problem I have is that when I put the second operator=() it seems to cancel out the first. Also, I tried adding methods for String::String(int) and such, but when I do `s=123;` for example, it says cannot convert String to int.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I thought he was trying to define an = operator which would be called for the object on the right hand side of the equal sign. But I learnt something today. Did not know about conversion operators before, and obviously, that's what's appropriate for one of the scenarios he described.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **single-argument constructor** can act as an int->String conversion, whereas a so-called **conversion operator** does the converse int->String

```
class String
{
public:
    String(int)            {} // initialization of String with int
    String& operator=(int) {} // assignment of int to String

    operator int() const {} // String to int
};
```

Note however, that these conversions will happen implicitly and you can easily get bitten. Suppose you would extend this class to also accept `std::string` arguments and conversions

```
class String
{
public:
    String(int)          {} // int to String
    String(std::string)  {} // std::string to String

    // plus two assignment operators 

    operator int() const       {} // String to int
    operator std::string const {} // String to std::string
};
```

and you would have these two function overloads

```
void fun(int)         { // bla }
void fun(std::string) { // bla }
```

Now try and call `fun(String())`. You get a compile error because there are multiple -equally viable- implicit conversions. THat's why C++98 allows the keyword `explicit` in front of single-argument constructors, and C++11 extends that to `explicit` conversion operators.

So you would write:

```
class String
{
public:
    explicit String(int)          {} // int to String
    explicit operator int() const {} // String to int 
};
```

One example where implicit conversion might be legitate is for smart pointer classes that want to convert to `bool` or (if they are templated) from `smart_pointer<Derived>` to `smart_pointer<Base>`.

Comment: I tried `String::String(int n)` and the line `s=123;` where s is the string seems to be an invalid conversion. Does it only work for the constructor?

Comment: With a constructor you could do either `String s(123);` or `String s = 123;`, but not `String s; s = 123;`. The latter is assignment, not initialization (so you would need to provide more assignment operators).

Comment: Ah, thanks. Much clearer now. What I actually need to do is assignment, sorry for the misunderstanding :)

Comment: @kvanberendonck Having multiple assignment operators or constructors is not bad in itself, what is bad is having multiple implicit conversion operators from `String` to all those types as well. Best make those `explicit` or write member functions like `as_int()`

Answer (score 4):

Rather than assignment operators, you probably want conversion
operators—there's no way you can define an additional assignment
operator for `int`.  In your `String` class, you might write:

```
class String
{
    //  ...
public:
    String( int i );           //  Converting constructor: int->String
    operator int() const;      //  conversion operator: String->int
    //  ...
};
```

You can add assignment operators in addition to the first, but they
generally aren't necessary except for optimization reasons.

And finally, I think you'll find this a bad idea.  It's good if the goal
is obfuscation, but otherwise, implicit conversions tend to make the
code less readable, and should be avoided except in obvious cases (e.g.
a `Complex` class should have a converting constructor from `double`).
Also, too many implicit conversions will result in ambiguities in
overload resolution.

Answer (score 2):

To convert your class to the other you need `conversion operator`. Something like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    operator int() const //Foo to int 
    {
        return 10;
    }

    operator=(int val) //assign int to Foo
    {

    }

    operator=(const std::string &s) //assign std::string to Foo
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the purpose of the operator=() then? Also, I don't think the above works if, for example, I need to convert an integer and store it in the string buffer rather than converting my class to another value type.

Comment: @kvanberendonck: operator=() is used to assign to Foo

Comment: @kvanberendonck: The first (conversion) operator allows you to write `integer = string;`. The second (assigment) operator allows you to write `string = integer;`.

Comment: What if I need to use multiple `operator=(someType x);` How do I do that?

Comment: @kvanberendonck: you can overload `operator=` as any other function. I added one more operator to the example

Comment: Got it working like this, thanks! One more thing, I can't seem to construct my operator=()'s without putting void before them. I get a type expected error. Is this normal?

Comment: @kvanberendonck: Like any function, they need a return type. You could return nothing (`void`), but it's conventional to return a reference to the object being assigned: `String & operator=(int x) {... return *this;}`. That allows users to chain assignments, `string1 = string2 = integer;`.

Answer (score 1):

To enable `int n = a` (where a is an object of your string class) you need a conversion operator.

```
class string {
  public:
    operator int() const { return 23; }
};
```

To enable conversion to your type, you need a converting assignment and possibly a conversion constructor.

```
class string {
  public:
    string(int i);
    string& operator=(int i);
};
```

You will also need overloads for `const char*`, `char*` and so on.